# Get IPv4 address from net tcp connection

Tags: go

I am trying to print out a log when a new TCP client connects to my Go server.

```golang
        l, err := net.Listen("tcp", bindPort)
        c, err := l.Accept()
        clientIP := c.RemoteAddr().String()
        fmt.Println("==> accepted new client, IP:", clientIP)
```

outputs from my testing on localhost

```
==> accepted new client, IP: [::1]:56780
```

I didn't find any way to get or convert it to an IPv4 (192.168.1.31) form.

Comment: You can't "convert" the address if the clients connects via IPv6, and it clearly connects via the loopback interface (localhost), so that address you want isn't in play in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use IPv4, you may force it to listen to IPv4 only

```
bindPort := "0.0.0.0:1234"
// or to be more specific, bindPort := "192.168.1.31:1234"
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", bindPort)
```

I assume you run golang on Linux, IPv6 is more like a default listener if you use default kernel options.

And also, if you want to connect *not as localhost*, you can specify the binding address to connect to server. I.e:

```
client, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.1.31:1234")
```

Comment: thanks, or if I want localhost, I can use the implicit 127.0.0.1 and force it into IPv4, it works